# Why does this statement hold?

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima, open-map

I have seen the following statement:

Let $G\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, bounded and $f:\overline{G}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a continuous and open map. Then $\|f\|$ gets its maximum on the boundary of $G$.

Why does this holds? Could you explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you mean that $f|_G$ is open.

If the maximum was attained at a point $p$ ouside the boundary, then $p$ would belong to $G$. But, since $f|_G$ is open, the range of $f$ must contain an open ball centered at $p$, contradicting the assumption about the maximum.

Comment: Do you mean that it should be $f|_G:\overline{G}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ ? Or do you mean $f|_G:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ or something else?If the maximum is attained at $p$ why is it not possible that there exists an open ball centered at $p$ ? I got stuck right now.

Comment: @MaryStar I mean that $f$ is continuous and that $f|_G$ is open. And if the range of $f$ contains an open ball of radius $r$ centered at $f(p)$, then there will be points $q$ such that $\|f(q)\|\in(\|f(p)\|,\|f(p)\|+r)$. In particular, $\|f(q)\|>\|f(p)\|$.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you so much!! :-)

Comment: Do you maybe have also an idea for my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822587/image-of-each-open-subset-is-open